# Database for mobile application in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, cross-platform, mobile-application

I would write a mobile application in Visual Studio 2012,I would make it cross-platform using Portable Class Library,but I'm not really sure which technology I should use for the database behind the application. The users of my application should not edit the data in the database,my app would only display some data,and I don't want to refresh data very often..so I thought I could make updates,I don't want internet connection to be needed while using the application. For mobile phones LINQ to SQL would work?

Comment: sqlite is the way to go

Comment: thanks :) I've heard before that it works very well on anrdoid and ios,but I wasn't sure if it's the best solution for windows too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is a very good approach and you can use LINQ for querying and also can be used in different platforms. As you said, in your situation having a local database is a very good idea instead of using internet.